# (Maple) Linear Combination of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, maple

**Problem**: [This problem is intended to be done with Maple] Suppose that:

$$\textbf{u}_1=\begin{pmatrix}
356\\ -185\\ -580\\ -918\\ 147\\ 468\\ 504\\ 594
\end{pmatrix},
\textbf{u}_2=\begin{pmatrix}
573\\ 230\\ -950\\ -877\\ 69\\ 677\\ 323\\ 486
\end{pmatrix},
\textbf{u}_3=\begin{pmatrix}
-1000\\ -833\\ 552\\ 935\\ -999\\ -483\\ 450\\ 457
\end{pmatrix},
\textbf{u}_4=\begin{pmatrix}
946\\ -379\\ -971\\ -840\\ 979\\ -591\\ -139\\ -451
\end{pmatrix}$$

Also suppose that $A = (\textbf{u}_1|\textbf{u}_2|\textbf{u}_3|\textbf{u}_4)$. Let $\textbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}-27\\59\\-75\\21\end{pmatrix}$. Hence let $A\textbf{v}$ is a linear combination in the form

$$\lambda_1\textbf{u}_1 + \lambda_2\textbf{u}_2 + \lambda_3\textbf{u}_3 + \lambda_4\textbf{u}_4$$

What are the values of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$.

**My attempts**

> If I'm being honest, I've been messing with the LinearAlegbra package for several hours and I have no idea if I'm on the right track. The first thing I did was use Gaussian Elimination on $A$ (which I defined as $B$), then used LinearSolve($B$,$\textbf{v}$) to find the values, although I do not believe this is correct (or at least the times I've tried always resulted in incorrect values).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A := Matrix([u1, u2, u3, u4]);

N := Matrix([A, A.v]);

ReducedRowEchelonForm(N);

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need Maple for this at all; I can't see how it would be useful except to verify. There is also no reason to use Gaussian Elimination to reduce the matrix.

You just need the definition of $A\mathbf{v}$; this is commonly defined as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, using the entries of $\mathbf{v}$ as weights. So
$\lambda_{1} = -27$, $\lambda_{2}=59$, $\lambda_{3}=-75$, $\lambda_{4}=21$.